# A question on metrizability

Tags: general-topology

In Munkres, Topology, there is a theorem 10.3
Let $f:X\to Y$ Let X be a matrizable. The function f is continuous iff for every convergenct sequence $x_{n}\to x$ in X, the sequence $f(x_{n})\to f(x)$. 
Which part of this statement implies there is a metric associated with Y? The only place I can guess a metric induced is thru the continous mapping f somehow to get it. However, I am not certain.

Comment: Do you mean Theorem 21.3?

Comment: Well, I guess I am using the 1st edition then? It is definitely not 2nd edition.

Comment: It's 21.3 in the second edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for $Y$ to be metrizable. The convergence $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ makes sense anyway, so there is no need for a metric.

The following example may give some intuition. Let $X=\mathbb R$ (usual metrizable topology), $Y=\{0,1\}$ (minimal topology) and $f:X\to Y$ so that $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\neq0$. This mapping $f$ is continuous and surjective, but $Y$ is not metrizable.